# Error compiling VexCL program: raw_ptr not a member of device_vector

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I am trying to compile my first VexCL program using the thrust example and I get the following error message:

raw_ptr is not a member of 'vex::backend::opencl::device_vector'

Here is the code

```
vex::Context ctx(vex::Filter::Env && vex::Filter::Count(1));
std::cout << ctx << std::endl;

vex::profiler<> prof(ctx);

typedef int T;
const size_t n = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
vex::vector<T> x(ctx, n);
vex::Random<T> rnd;

// Get raw pointers to the device memory.
T *x_begin = x(0).raw_ptr(); // Here is where the error is occurring.
T *x_end   = x_begin + x.size();
```

I do not understand the language well enough. I appreciate any help in this matter.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thrust example is not the best to start with, as it deals with interfacing [VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl) and [Thrust](https://thrust.github.io/) (another high-level library that is targeted on CUDA).
So in order to compile the example, you need to use the `CUDA` backend in VexCL. That is, you need to define `VEXCL_BACKEND_CUDA` preprocessor macro
and to link against `libcuda.so` (or `cuda.lib` if on Windows) instead of `libOpenCL.so`/`OpenCL.lib`.

The error you got is because the `device_vector` class only exposes `raw_ptr()` method when on CUDA backend.